# FFMPEG: Output to a new file after certain period of time with creation time stamp?

Tags: ffmpeg, output, segment

Suppose I have a command:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video1 -c:v libx265 -x265-params bitrate=60:vbv-maxrate=60:vbv-bufsize=16:keyint=10:qcomp=0.5 -tune zerolatency -s 640x480 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 5 -strict experimental -f somedate.ts
```

What I want to do is that after 30 minutes ffmpeg starts writing the stream to new file with filename as time of creation of new file.

Comment: one option is to just start ffmpeg, do the recording by passing in a file "with the currentt time" then starting ffmpeg again, loop style (bash loop style) though you might lose some frames between instantiations.

Comment: @rogerdpack Wouldn't it mess the start PTS? It'll reset the timestamps to (near) 0 for the next segments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the segmenter instead of `-f somedate.ts` plus `strftime`:

```
-f segment -segment_time 1800 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts
```

Where `1800 = 30 * 60` seconds.

Comment: Thank you Aergistal. Works Perfect :)